# Android: Bing Maps API - ZOOM IN programmatically

Tags: android, bing-maps, bing, bing-api

I need to make default scale of

```
 MapView map = new MapView(this, MapRenderMode.VECTOR);
```

twice as large (zoom in). I'm using **Android Java**, no JS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to zoom in by 2x each time, zoom level is appropriate. Each zoom level is 2x the previous one. For your map instance:

```
map.setScene(MapScene.createFromLocationAndZoomLevel(map.getCenter(), map.getZoomLevel + 1), MapAnimationKind.LINEAR);
```